# Language from client to WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a SOAP-Oriented WCF service which has some globalization functionalities and a client which send messages to the server so it replies with the data. I want to set globalization on both server and client.

Client side was easy and smooth but when I am now facing the server side I don't know how to send the language from the client to the server so I can set the language properly.

Is there any way to do so?

Comment: You can send it as part of SOAP header. use `MessageContract` for this purpose

Comment: If the service supports globalization then I should have some way which you can use to tell service to use specific language. You need to go thru the documentation of the service